# Ejecutar PyQt dentro de C++

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt

Quiero ejecutar PyQT dentro de un programa en C++ que estoy haciendo. Hasta ahora todas las pruebas están siendo infructuosas.

Pasos que doy. Primero pruebo fuera de C++

1.- Creo una interfaz con Qt Designer. En este caso un sencillo widget con un `QPushButton`
2.- Con la herramiento `pyuic5` creo el modulo de pyhon referente a ese widget. Sale algo como:

**ui_widget.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'widget.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.5.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 130, 85, 27))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
```

Ahora creo otro módulo que hace uso de este:

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from ui_widget import Ui_Form


class MiWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)       

def iniciar():
    print ("iniciar ventanas")
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MiWidget()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Y por último lo llamo desde la consola:

```
usuario@sobremesa ~/programacion/python/PyQt $ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from main import iniciar
>>> iniciar()
iniciar ventanas
```

Y todo sale correctamente.

Ahora toca hacer la llamada desde C++:

```
#include "/usr/include/python3.5m/Python.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    PyObject* fExportar = nullptr;
    PyObject* modulo = nullptr;
    PyObject* pName = nullptr;
    const char *scriptDirectoryName = "/home/usuario/programacion/python/PyQt/";
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
    PyObject *path = PyUnicode_FromString(scriptDirectoryName);
    int result = PyList_Insert(sysPath, 0, path);
    if (result == 0 )
    {
        pName = PyUnicode_FromString("main");
        modulo = PyImport_Import(pName);
        std::cout<<"modulo "<<modulo<<std::endl;
        PyObject *args = PyTuple_New(0);
        Py_DECREF(path);
        if (modulo)
        {
            fExportar = PyObject_GetAttrString(modulo, "iniciar");
            Py_DECREF(modulo);
            if (fExportar)
            {
                std::cout<<"Funcion exportar: "<<" -- "<<fExportar<<std::endl;
                PyObject_CallObject(fExportar,args);
            }
        }
    }
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Pero hace la llamada a la función correctamente, o al menos imprime "iniciar ventanas", pero no sale ninguna ventana. Bueno, creo que tal vez arranque la ventana pero no se mantiene en el loop por lo que se abre y se cierra de forma que no se vea nada. Eso es mi suposición.
En todo caso, ¿Cómo habré de llamar a la función para que se muestre la ventana correctamente y, si es el caso, se quede ejecutando el script de python hasta que se cierre la misma y vuelva el control al programa principal? (puede ser que esté diciendo cosas sin sentido)

Comment: Da gusto preguntas tan bien planteadas, formuladas, y con su correspondiente ejemplo mínimo :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pues parece que he resuelto el problema.

Lo primero, es crear un entorno seguro para cargar los módulos, evitando en la medida de los posible los errores de segmentación y así de paso poder ver qué es lo que realmente falla. No hay que inventar nada, sino adaptar el [código propuesto](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding) en la página oficial a las necesidades. En mi caso lo pongo como una función. Aquí completo:

```
#include "/usr/include/python3.5m/Python.h"

int EjecutaFuncionPython(const char* ruta, const char* nombremodulo, const char* nombrefuncion);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    putenv((char*)"PYTHONPATH=/home/user/programacion/python/PyQt/");
    Py_Initialize();    
    EjecutaFuncionPython("/home/user/programacion/python/PyQt/","main","iniciar");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}


int EjecutaFuncionPython(const char* ruta, const char* nombremodulo, const char* nombrefuncion)
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(nombremodulo);
    /* Error checking of pName left out */
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if (pModule != NULL)
    {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, nombrefuncion);
        /* pFunc is a new reference */

        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
        {
            pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
            pValue = PyUnicode_FromString(ruta);
            if (!pValue)
            {
                Py_DECREF(pArgs);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
                return 1;
            }
            /* pValue reference stolen here: */
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);

            pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);
            if (pValue != NULL)
            {
                printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyLong_AsLong(pValue));
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
            }
            else
            {
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", nombrefuncion);
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", nombremodulo);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Ahora puedo ver que el error que me arroja es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/programacion/python/PyQt/main.py", line 19, in iniciar
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'argv'
Call failed
```

Y por último, viendo problemas similares, [esta solución](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/issues/642#issuecomment-279643203) me funciona

Eso quiere decir que a mi script en python le añado esto:

```
if not hasattr(sys, 'argv'): #nuevas lineas
        sys.argv  = [''] #nuevas lineas
```

Y me queda así:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from ui_widget import Ui_Form


class MiWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)       

def iniciar():
    print ("iniciar ventanas python3")
    if not hasattr(sys, 'argv'): #nuevas lineas
        sys.argv  = [''] #nuevas lineas
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  #aqui el error
    myapp = MiWidget()
    myapp.show()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Y ya funciona.

Por añadir algo más, y siguiendo la documentación oficial, a la hora de compilar es bueno averiguar las opciones adecuadas. Para ello está la utilidad **pythonx.y-config** (donde x.y es la versión de python) seguido de --cflags y --ldflags

En mi caso `python3.5-config --cflags --ldflags`

Con este resultado (cada uno tendrá el suyo):

```
-I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/usr/include/python3.5m  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
-L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

Answer (score 1):

De la documentación de [PyObject_CallObject( )](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallObject):

> **PyObject_CallObject( PyObject *callable, PyObject *args )**
>   
>   Call a callable Python object callable, with arguments given by the tuple args. If no arguments are needed, then args can be NULL.

Traducción y resaltados mios:

> Realiza una llamada a un *callable* de `python`, con los argumentos pasados en la tupla `args`. **Si no son necesarios argumentos, entonces `args` puede ser `NULL`**.

En **python2.7**, la solución es, sencillamente, pasar `nullptr` como segundo argumento en la llamada a la función `PyObject_CallObject( )`. Basta con modificar tu código

```
    PyObject *args = PyTuple_New(0);
    Py_DECREF(path);
    if (modulo)
    {
        fExportar = PyObject_GetAttrString(modulo, "iniciar");
        Py_DECREF(modulo);
        if (fExportar)
        {
            std::cout<<"Funcion exportar: "<<" -- "<<fExportar<<std::endl;
            PyObject_CallObject(fExportar,args);
```

eliminado la llamada a `PyTuple_New( )`para que quede así:

```
    Py_DECREF(path);
    if (modulo)
    {
        fExportar = PyObject_GetAttrString(modulo, "iniciar");
        Py_DECREF(modulo);
        if (fExportar)
        {
            std::cout<<"Funcion exportar: "<<" -- "<<fExportar<<std::endl;
            PyObject_CallObject(fExportar,nullptr);
```

Y la ventana aparece.

Comment: Hola. Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero no funciona. Realmente añado la mejora a mi código, y veo que es la forma correcta de llamar a una función sin argumentos, pero el resultado es igual. Realmente yo consigo llamar a la función de python, pero el problema es que no se ejecuta la ventana, o como sospecho, no se ejecuta el loop, y entonces la ventana probablemente se abra y se cierre sin más.

Comment: Lo he probado, y a mi si me funciona, **pero** en python2.7. El conportamiento erróneo es el mismo, así que asumí que la solución serviría también. Bueno, que se le va a hacer. Indicaré la versión en la respuesta.

Comment: Hola de nuevo. ¿Intento con ```python/python3``` y ```PyQt4/PyQt5``` respectivamente y funciona correctamente en mi consola, pero no dentro de mi programa en C++. No se me ocurre qué más puedo mirar. Esta es la secuencia de compilado para python 2: ```g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -pedantic-errors -std=c++11  -c /home/usuario/programacion/cmasmas/PythonC++/py2/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o``` y ```g++  -o bin/Debug/py2 obj/Debug/main.o   ../../../../../../usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so```

Comment: Hombre, se lee muy feo al usar las rutas absolutas, pero es correcto :-) Estoy en el curro ahora, aquí no tengo lo necesario instalado. Luego le echaré otro vistazo a ver si se me ocurre algo. Pero tardaré bastante.

Comment: Je je...he copiado el build log a lo bestia :-) Muchas gracias por el interés!